# If 2 different radios are selected, Do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I essentially have 1 radio selection with a few colours, all with the same attributes, just different values, using an onclick event to pass on the value. worked great, it would allow the user to click on a color(radio) and it would display an image.

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ktmzy8L0/

The above now includes another radio selection called pattern. But every where I searched cant seem to find an answer to solve this.

Essential - If the user selects 2 separate radios [different names], show a different picture. If you are following the jsfiddle it would show a blue diamond(I would use a url to show the image depending on the 2 radio values they choose) and the image would popup in showpicture.

The below code I originally have for jquery

```
  function CB(colorbackground) {
  var url;
  $('#showpictureheader').show();
  $('#showpicture').show();
  if (colorbackground == "Navy Blue") {
    url = "https://www.colorhexa.com/023333.png";
    document.getElementById("showpicture").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
    $('#showpictureheader').text('Navy Blue Pattern');
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem", where it says, in part, "but **also copy the code into the question itself.**" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Hi Heretic, I  put the jsfiddle with the whole working code

Comment: Maybe there was a language barrier... The code needs to be here on Stack Overflow, in the question. It can also be on jsfiddle, but it must be on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes it more dynamic. Simply add `data-color='ff0000'` to the bg color radio buttons. Then this code will simply take the selected pattern value and bg color radio and show the title and selected bgcolor.

```js
bgcolor = "";
pattern = "";

$("input[type='radio']").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).prop("name") == "properties[Background Color]"){
       bgcolor = $(this);
    }
    else if($(this).prop("name") == "properties[Background Pattern]"){
        pattern = $(this);
    }
    
    if(bgcolor && pattern){
      $('#showpictureheader').show();
      $('#showpicture').show();
       url = "https://www.colorhexa.com/" + bgcolor.data("color") + ".png";
       document.getElementById("showpicture").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
       $('#showpictureheader').text(bgcolor.val() + ' ' + pattern.val());
    }
});
```

```css
    .background-choices label>input {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .background-choices label>input+img {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .background-choices label>input+img {
            border: 2px solid transparent;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
        }
    }

    .background-choices label>input:checked+img {
        border: 5px solid #fd8252;
    }

    .background-choices label>input:not(:checked)+img {
        border: 5px solid #f4f5f5;
    }

    .background-choices label:hover {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
  
    .background-tab-wrapper h3 {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
  
  #showpictureheader {
        display: none;
  }
  
  .showpictureheader{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  #showpicture {
        border: 5px solid #f4f5f5;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 10px 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        margin: auto;
        display: none;
        background-size: contain;
  }
```

```html
<div class="background-choices">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <h3>Color</h3>
                    <label>
                        <input data-color="000080" id="background-choice-input1" type="radio" name="properties[Background Color]" class="background-choices-selector" value="Navy Blue"/>
                        <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/000080.png">
                    </label>
                    <h3>Pattern</h3>
                    <label>
                        <input id="background-choice-input2" type="radio" name="properties[Background Pattern]" value="Diamond"/>
                        <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/884/524/png-transparent-diamond-rhombus-shape-oval-outline-s-blue-angle-white-thumbnail.png">
                    </label>
                </div>
  <div class="showpictureheader">
      <h7 id="showpictureheader"></h7>
  </div>
  <div id="showpicture">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is, you should separate to one more function.

```js
function CB(bg) {
  var url;
  $('#showpictureheader').show();
  $('#showpicture').show();
  if (bg == "Navy Blue") {
    url = "https://www.colorhexa.com/023333.png";
    document.getElementById("showpicture").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
  }
}

function secondcb() {
  $('#showpictureheader').text('Navy Blue Pattern');
}
```

```css
.background-choices label>input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.background-choices label>input+img {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .background-choices label>input+img {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}

.background-choices label>input:checked+img {
  border: 5px solid #fd8252;
}

.background-choices label>input:not(:checked)+img {
  border: 5px solid #f4f5f5;
}

.background-choices label:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.background-tab-wrapper h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#showpictureheader {
  display: none;
}

.showpictureheader {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#showpicture {
  border: 5px solid #f4f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-choices">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h3>Color</h3>
  <label>
    <input id="background-choice-input1" type="radio" name="properties[Background Color]" class="background-choices-selector" value="Navy Blue" onClick="CB(this.value);"/>
    <img src="https://www.colorhexa.com/000080.png">
  </label>
  <h3>Pattern</h3>
  <label>
    <input onchange="secondcb()" id="background-choice-input2" type="radio" name="properties[Background Pattern]" value="Diamond"/>
    <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/884/524/png-transparent-diamond-rhombus-shape-oval-outline-s-blue-angle-white-thumbnail.png">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="showpictureheader">
  <h7 id="showpictureheader"></h7>
</div>
<div id="showpicture">
</div>
```